# Blender Cycles To Make Hair Thinner?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles

I am kind of new to Blender Cycles and I don't know how to make hair with the particle system thinner. I am looking it up everywhere and cannot find an answer.

[image]

Comment: Can you show us what you have so far and your current particle settings?

Comment: Yes, what panels shall I show?

Comment: Here I use imgur https://imgur.com/a/pT9wJ

Comment: I am also want to make the hair move slightly when the model moves, and a lot when there is wind.

Comment: Please don't post images in the comments, use the edit link below your question. Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71480/hair-does-not-show-up-in-final-render and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73937/no-cycles-hair-rendering-options-in-2-78 and use search before asking

Comment: I still need help this isnt a duplicate

Comment: What help do you need?